# Unable to read analyze 7.5 image in c

Tags: c, image-processing

I was trying to read voxel information of a 3D analyze image.
Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    unsigned int R,G,B;
    unsigned char data[3];
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    fp = fopen("67.img", "rb");
    ft = fopen("OUT.txt", "w");
    while (fread(data, 3, 1, fp) == 1) {
        R = data[0];
        G = data[1];
        B = data[2];
        fprintf(ft, "%u,%u,%u:", R, G, B);        
    }
}
```

But in the "Out.txt" I am not getting expected RGB values.

[image: Header information]Header information:

I am a newbie in C.
Please help me.

Comment: What do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: The Image contain black Background with Blue Big sphere. But the values are not in the shade of blue.

Comment: The Image contain black Background with Blue Big sphere. But the values are not in the shade of blue. There has point of color code 10,15,170 (blue) But I am getting these values in the out put. All value in the text are mainly in gray scale (e.g. 0,0,0 1,1,1 15,14,15 110,111,108 85,132,137 etc)

Comment: The code looks fine (apart from void main) - check the contents of your img file with a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

fread is size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

Your size should be 1 and your count 3. You have them reversed.  I'd try switching them, as well as the while loop, and seeing if that works.